# List of Dictionary Values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-itertools

I have the dictionary as below:

```
tf ={1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2: ['d', 'x', 'y']}
```

I want to form the list of values as:

```
wrd_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'y']
```

I tried to do this by using the following code:

```
wrd_list = []
for k, v in tf.items():
    for i in v:
        word_list.append(i)
```

is there any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using extend here is faster than append when you want to concatenate lists:

```
word_list = []
for v in tf.values():
    word_list.extend(v)
```